# Why String is not a String when it is passed to C from Scheme?

Tags: c, racket

From the Plt-Scheme installation I have an example of C/Scheme interaction. There are two files: curses.c and curses-demo.ss. These files are available [here](http://pre.plt-scheme.org/plt/collects/mzscheme/examples/).
I've compiled curses.c, and trying to run curses-demo.ss

And I am getting the following error: "put: expects argument of type 'character, string, or byte string'; given "Hello World!""

It looks strange. Have any ideas what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those examples are quite old, and it seems that they suffer from a number of additional problems.  If you need to interact with C code, it is much easier to do with the "new" foreign interface -- look at the [foreign manual](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/foreign/).